# An error occurred while getting provider information from the database error in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

so, I was trying to follow the tutorial of MVC from [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application). When I'm in **Set up and Execute a Code First Migration** part and enter `enable-migrations -contexttypename SchoolContext` on Package Manager Console, I got this error :

> An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct.

So, what really happen with this error? I'm new in MVC, I'm just started to learn MVC.

Thanks for your attention for this question.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to see the relevant web.config sections.
Here is an example for a local SQL Server Express:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyDB" connectionString="Data Source=MyServer;Initial Catalog=DBName;Integrated Security=SSPI;persist security info=True;Asynchronous Processing=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```